# Shouldn't CChain::Next check if the given block is the tip block or not?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

This function [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chain.h#L467) gives a pointer to a block, and return the succesor block of that pointer.

```
    /** Find the successor of a block in this chain, or nullptr if the given index is not found or is the tip. */
    CBlockIndex* Next(const CBlockIndex* pindex) const
    {
        if (Contains(pindex))
            return (*this)[pindex->nHeight + 1];
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
```

If the given block is containing in the chain, it attempt to return the successor. So if the `Chain.Tip()` is given, it tries to reach the successor while there is no successor of the tip block. Isn't it better to check if `nHeight` of the given block is less than the `Chain.Tip().nHeight - 1` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not guarantee that the currently inspected block has a successor. While eventually the network converges on a single best chain, the network does temporarily fork occasionally, when two miners find a block at the same height. If a node were on the chaintip that is being reorged out there could be a block with a greater height, while it is not the successor of the node's current best block. Insofar, we must handle blocks not having successors anyway, so I assume that the `nullptr` is handled benignly somewhere in the surrounding code (I haven't checked, though).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I checked it here, it handled in the `[]` operator. Thanks for your answer. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chain.h#L453

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to check the `[]` operator of the `CChain` class. The implementation is:

```
    /** Returns the index entry at a particular height in this chain, or nullptr if no such height exists. */
    CBlockIndex* operator[](int nHeight) const
    {
        if (nHeight < 0 || nHeight >= (int)vChain.size())
            return nullptr;
        return vChain[nHeight];
    }
```

So by calling the `(*this)[pindex->nHeight + 1]` the operator that is overloaded is called and if the `nHeight` is greater that the `vChain.size()` it returns the `nullptr`.